# how to use child_process in older version of node and webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, dependencies

My application is working on node version 0.10.48.
Which isn't allowing me to use  child_process dependency.

`var exec = require('child_process');`

getting below error

**nModule not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process'**

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/child_process.html it’s part of 0.10. Is your install messed up?  Also that’s really old. End of life was 4.5 years ago.

Comment: Agree Joe, But this issue is in other teammate machines too. That concludes either everyone else has messed up their environment or node isn't working with webpack.

Comment: wait, webpack -- how are you trying to use `child_process`?  That can only be used server-side in the node process, and not browser-side via webpack.

Comment: I am using in electron. its working in some other project. only difference in that project and mine is node version. they are both running in same machine